# rotate and transform-origin in Chrome

Tags: css, svg

According to the documentation, if I want to rotate an SVG element around its center, all I have to do is add 2 lines in the css file:

```
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
```

In reality, however, the element gets rotated around the center of the SVG rather than the center of the element. Am I doing something wrong or is it the expected behavior? 
See the demonstration here: https://codepen.io/lkaratun/pen/YLzgdG

I'm using Chrome 65, addind -webkit- prefix didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected. You need to set transform-box: fill-box to get things to work the way you want.

You should also note that setting x, y, fill, height, cx, cy, r as CSS properties instead of as attributes is only currently supported in Chrome. Here's a cross browser solution.

```css
rect {
  fill: red;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform-origin: center;
}
circle {
  fill:black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"">
<rect width="100px" height="50px" x="50px" y="50px"/>
<circle cx="100px" cy="75px" r="5px"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I never saw any mentions of transform-box when reading about svg rotations